# How to check if value 1 follows value 2, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have quite the large dataframe, kinda looking like this:

```
nr | light | date | ...
-----------------------
 1 |  off  | ...  | ...
 1 |  on   | ...  | ...
 1 |  off  | ...  | ...
 1 |  on   | ...  | ...
 2 |  off  | ...  | ...
 2 |  on   | ...  | ...
 2 |  off  | ...  | ...
...
```

Now, I would like to write a function that checks if after every "off" follows an "on".

It would be even better if said function could show exactly where it is not the case.

Does anyone maybe have a tip for me? I am still new in using python / pandas. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming that you only care about on/off transitions in the same nr.  So you must groupby nr and then go through each and check.  Without this constraint it's almost a one-liner.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'nr' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'lights' : ['on','off','on','off','on','off','on','off','off']})
df
```

gives

```
    nr  lights
0   1   on
1   1   off
2   1   on
3   1   off
4   2   on
5   2   off
6   2   on
7   2   off
8   2   off
```

then do

```
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
output['problem'] = False
for num, subdf in df.groupby('nr'):
    subdf['prev'] = subdf['lights'].shift()
    subdf['problem'] = np.where((subdf['lights'] == 'off') & (subdf['prev'] == 'off'), True, False)
    output = pd.concat([output,subdf])
output

    nr  lights  problem prev
0   1   on      False   NaN
1   1   off     False   on
2   1   on      False   off
3   1   off     False   on
4   2   on      False   NaN
5   2   off     False   on
6   2   on      False   off
7   2   off     False   on
8   2   off     True    off
```

Which has all the problems in the true value

Comment: Thank you very, very much! Also for your explanation, it helps a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This will return any records where the status did not change.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'nr': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 'light': ['off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'on']})

df.loc[df['light'].eq(df['light'].shift(1))]
```

Output

```
    nr  light
5   2   off
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the DataFrame I have created:

```
nr  lights
0   0   off
1   1   on
2   2   off
3   3   off
4   4   on
```

To check if all of the lights are on:

```
all(pf['lights']=='on')
```

And to check the ones that are off:

```
pf[pf.loc[:,'lights']=='off']
```

Hope this responds to your question.